# Import custom scala object in jupyter notebook with sparkContext.addFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I've a Jupyter Notebook where i'm trying to import a keys as a string from an outside function. In pyspark all work without problems with this code

**Config.py**

```
credentials = {"item1": "prueba"}

def get_key(storage_account):
    return credentials[storage_account]
```

Call in the notebook:

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile("/home/joaco/data-experiment/notebooks_fpatito/readExternalFilesNotebook/pySpark/Config.py")
import Config
key = Config.get_key("item1")
print(key)
```

[image]

But, when I'm trying to do the same in Scala Spark the notebook throw me a not found error

> "not found: value testMap"

**testMap.scala**

```
object testMap {

  val mapExample = Map(
    "item1" -> "item1value",
    "item2" -> "item2value",
    "item3" -> "item3value",
  )

}
```

I'm doing the same sparkContext.addfile:

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile("/home/joaco/data-experiment/notebooks_fpatito/readExternalFilesNotebook/Spark/testMap.scala")
```

And this import: `import testMap._`

But the class is not found

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Python is an interpreted language but Scala is not, hence the Notebook throws Error when you try to load a Scala file like you did for a Python file.
You need to compile the Scala file to a class and make it available as a JAR. Then you can add the JAR to your path as follows:

1. `--jars` option on spark commandline
2. `spark.sparkContext.addJar(/path/to/JAR/file)`

Comment: But if I add file with addJar I have the same problem "Not Found Value". how should it be imported?